# Using SED to replace a pattern causes extra characters to appear

Tags: regex, bash, sed

I have a file and want to replace a pattern with another string.

```
#PBS -N bench1-M1-plt2-size15
#PBS -o /home/results/bench1-M1-plt2-size15.out
./run -d ./results/ --config=bench1-M1-plt2-size15.conf \ 
--results=bench1-M1-plt2-size15.res config/myConfig.txt -F 2000000
```

I use this command

```
sed 's/M1-[^-]*-[^-]/M1-plt32-size10/g' filename
```

However the output file looks like this:

```
#PBS -N M1-plt32-size100
#PBS -o /home/mahmood/gem5/results/M1-plt32-size100.out
./run -d ./results/ --config=bench1-M1-plt32-size100.conf \
--results=bench1-M1-plt32-size100.res config/myConfig.txt -F 2000000
```

Please note an extra '0' character after "size10". As you can see, in the SED command, size is set to 10, however the output file is "size100"

What is the problem and how can I fix that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your regex is not correct. You have `[^-]` which will match only 1 non-hyphen character. I believe this is what you intended:

```
sed 's/M1-[^-]*-[^\.]*/M1-plt32-size10/' filename
```

**OUTPUT:**

```
#PBS -N bench1-M1-plt32-size10
#PBS -o /home/results/bench1-M1-plt32-size10.out
./run -d ./results/ --config=bench1-M1-plt32-size10.conf \ 
--results=bench1-M1-plt32-size10.res config/myConfig.txt -F 2000000
```

Comment: can you explain what does `[^\.]*` mean and what is the difference with `[^-]*`??

Comment: Yes sure. `[^\.]*` means 0 or more characters until dot `.` is found whereas `[^\-]*` means 0 or more characters until hyphen `-` is found. Since in your original text you have only 1 hyphen after `M1-` therefore I used `[^-]*-[^\.]*` to match `-plt2-size15` which is just before a dot `.`.